# Inno Setup: Failed to remove temporary directory - не удаляется временный файл dll

Tags: dll, inno-setup

При завершении работы установщика (завершение или отмена установки) не удаляется библиотека MyDll.dll из создаваемой установщиком временной папки (../AppData/Local/Temp/is-<символы>.tmp). Это происходит как при запуске от имени администратора, так и под обычным пользователем. В качестве основы использовался пример CodeDll.iss из папки Inno Setup 5/Examples. Используемая версия Inno Setup - 5.5.9.

Исходный код скрипта:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={userpf}\My Program
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
PrivilegesRequired=none

[Files]
Source: "MyDll.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Code]
const
  MB_ICONINFORMATION = $40;
procedure MyDllFuncSetup(hWnd: Integer; lpText, lpCaption: AnsiString; uType: Cardinal);
external 'MyDllFunc@{tmp}\MyDll.dll stdcall delayload';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    hWnd: Integer;
begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('MyDll.dll')
    hWnd := StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}'));

    MyDllFuncSetup(hWnd, 'Hello from custom DLL function', 'MyDllFunc', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    Result := True;
    UnloadDLL(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyDll.dll'));
end;
```

Исходный код библиотечной функции:

```
#include <windows.h>

void __stdcall MyDllFunc(HWND hWnd, char *lpText, char *lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
  MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}
```

Был также опробован следующий вариант

```
[Files]
    Source: "MyDll.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
    Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
    Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
    Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Code]
const
  MB_ICONINFORMATION = $40;
procedure MyDllFuncSetup(hWnd: Integer; lpText, lpCaption: AnsiString; uType: Cardinal);
external 'MyDllFunc@files:MyDll.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    hWnd: Integer;
begin
    hWnd := StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}'));

    MyDllFuncSetup(hWnd, 'Hello from custom DLL function', 'MyDllFunc', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    Result := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
    UnloadDLL(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyDll.dll'));
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyDll.dll'));
end;
```

Результат тот же.

Process Explorer при поиске данной библиотеки во время работы установщика выдает такой результат:

```
Process                 PID   Type  Name 
mysetup.tmp             4648  DLL   <путь к временной папке>/MyDll.dll
mysetup.tmp             4648  DLL   <путь к временной папке>/MyDll.dll
<Non-existent Process>  4648  File  <путь к временной папке>/MyDll.dll
```

mysetup.exe - файл установки.
mysetup.tmp - временный файл, создаваемый установщиком, но лежит он в другой временной папке, которая находится в (../AppData/Local/Temp). 
Попытки удаления данной библиотеки вручную на любом этапе установки блокируются.

Почему так происходит и как все-таки удалить этот файл?

Comment: Пробовали использовать флаг [deleteafterinstall](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection)?

Comment: @MaLS, пробовал, тоже не помогает. Я обнаружил, что проблема в самой dll, но в чем именно проблема пока не установил. Если dll собрать в msvc 2015, то никаких проблем не возникает.